# How do I receive data from my Service class into my ViewModel?

Tags: android, timer, android-service, viewmodel, android-livedata

I'm working on a project involving a CountdownTimer that will keep running even if the app is shut down. To ensure this, I'm using a Foreground Service that displays a notification showing that the app is running.

Now, when the timer is running within the service, I also want it to update a TextView in my Activity. Can anyone tell me how to get the current time from the CountdownTimer within the service to the Activity?

I've been learning ViewModels and LiveData for this purpose, but I cannot understand how to implement them.

Comment: Maybe I'm not the only one who haven't got point of your question. Can you clarify - what scenarios do you need to implement? What exactly you want your app do when: Case 1. There is no activity foreground and your user see only notification. If there is no activity then there is no TextView to update, right? Case 2. Your activity in foreground and some TextView has to be updated each Timer's interval, right? Or your question is only about Case 2?

Comment: It's about both the scenarios. When the app is in foreground, it should update the textview. But when it has been removed from the recent apps list, it should continue on, and a notification should be displayed that the timer is running.